# Check either a identifier is valid or not

Tags: c, identifier

```
        if (id[0]=='_' || id[0]>='A' && id[0]<='Z' || id[0]>='a' && id[0]<='z')
            {
                for(i=1;i<len;i++)
                 {
                     if(id[i]=='_' || id[i]<=9 && id[i]>=0 || id[i]>='A' && id[i]<='Z' || id[i]>='a' && id[i]<='z')
                        printf("%d",++count);
                            
                 }
                 //printf("final_count=%d\n",count);
                 if(count==len-1)
                      printf("The identifier is valid.\n");
                        
                else
                      printf("The identifier is not valid.\n");
            }
        else
            printf("The identifier is not valid.\n");
```

In this code checking identifier validity. For every kind of input it gives the right output but when I give _9kjh, num1 etc it shows not valid but it is valid. It happens only when a valid identifier with numaric value.

Comment: `id[i]<=9 && id[i]>=0` should have been `id[i]<='9' && id[i]>='0'`

Comment: @dratenik No, it should be `isdigit(id[i])`.  Likewise, `id[i]<=9 && id[i]>=0 || id[i]>='A' && id[i]<='Z' || id[i]>='a' && id[i]<='z'` should be [`isalnum()`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.4.1.1).

Comment: @AndrewHenle locale specific? Wouldn't that accept various accented characters? Are they intended to be valid identifiers? I don't know, do you? Let's not overcomplicate this, the core of OP's question was a 9 vs. '9' typo.

Comment: @dratenik If you're worried about locales, you wouldn't be hard-coding ASCII into your code anyway.  If that's an issue, you'd be setting your locale properly.  And my standards for C code are higher than assuming things not guaranteed by the C standard - assumptions like letters being represented consecutively.  Thinking something is "good enough" is a way to open a path to future hard-to-find bugs.

Comment: Well, I would be tempted to use a lookup table - just access a static const array of bits using div/mod 8.  For ASCII 0-127 you would only need 16 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

here you need to check every array element as a character. but `if(id[i]=='_' || id[i]<=9 && id[i]>=0` here you are comparing `id[i]` `char` with number. which is actually not desired thing.
need to update to `if(id[i]=='_' || id[i]<='9' && id[i]>='0'`

and also put every `&&` conditions under first parenthesis (). this will avoid further complication

```
        if (id[0]=='_' || (id[0]>='A' && id[0]<='Z') || (id[0]>='a' && id[0]<='z'))
            {
                for(i=1;i<len;i++)
                 {
                     if(id[i]=='_' || (id[i]<='9' && id[i]>='0') || (id[i]>='A' && id[i]<='Z') || (id[i]>='a' && id[i]<='z'))
                        printf("%d",++count);
                            
                 }
                 //printf("final_count=%d\n",count);
                 if(count==len-1)
                      printf("The identifier is valid.\n");
                        
                else
                      printf("The identifier is not valid.\n");
            }
        else
            printf("The identifier is not valid.\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure of your rules but maybe you want () on the two terms to check for letters at the start?

```
if (id[0]=='_' || (id[0]>='A' && id[0]<='Z') || (id[0]>='a' && id[0]<='z'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the standard C [`isalpha()`](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.4.1.2) and [`isalnum()`](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.4.1.1) functions

```
#include <ctype.h>

if (id[0]=='_' || isalpha(id[0]))
{
    for(i=1;i<len;i++)
    {
        if(id[i]=='_' || isalnum(id[i]))
        {
            printf("%d",++count);
        }
    }
    //printf("final_count=%d\n",count);
    if(count==len-1)
    {
        printf("The identifier is valid.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("The identifier is not valid.\n");
    }
}
else
{
    printf("The identifier is not valid.\n");
}
```

There are no guarantees that letter are represented consecutively, so code like `id[i]>='A' && id[i]<='Z'` isn't portable.  For that, you should use `isupper()`.

Note also the improved readability from using ***consistent*** indentation.

Comment: May classify `fůbäř` as a valid identifier under certain circumstances. This may or may not be what OP wanted. The A-Z thing will fail on EBCDIC, all other character sets in widespread use are sane enough not to have a discontinuous alphabet.

Comment: @dratenik [Ummm, it takes explicit action for that to happen](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.11.1.1p4).  You're not really trying to say that hardcoding ASCII is the solution to a portability problem?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the type of `id` is `char`, instead of `int`. Then use ASCII code.

Replace`if( id[i]<=9 && id[i]>=0 )` to `if(id[i]-'0' <= 9  && id[i]-'0' >= 0 )`.